# Load data up front in a console application c#

Tags: caching, memory, console-application

I have a console application which does some data processing. 
I need to load some data up front from database and cache them in memory during the process. What is the best way of doing it in c#?

Comment: Can you explain "Best way of doing it" Is it Loading from database/caching in memory ... ?

Comment: You have done any coding?

Comment: Yes loading from database and caching in memory and yes I am a software developer!